Can we find the root of this equation
Give an equation below:
$$
\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=c \qquad (1)
$$
where $1<a<x$, $0<k<1$, and $c>0$.
I can easily find the numerical root of (1) by using Newton's method or the other tools.
However, I still want to ask this question:
Can we find the closed-form root of (1) w.r.t. $x$?
Any helpful suggestions or answers will be greatly appreciated!

$x^k-cx+ac-a^k$ is a trinomial equation. There are series solutions for them which you can use. They have hypergeometric closed forms, in the link.

Thanks for your time!
This comment gives me an alternative to find the root!

I've been working in a new special function called Lambert-Tsallis, $W_r(z)$. Such a function is the solution of the following problem
$$W_r(z)\bigg( 1 + \frac{W_r(z)}{r} \bigg)^r= y\cdot e_r(y) = z,  \space  (1)$$ being $y= W_r(z)$ and $e_r(y) = \bigg( 1 + \frac{y}{r} \bigg)^r$.
There are different math problems that can be reduced to Eq. (1). Examples 1, 2 and so on.
After a few manipulations your original problem can be written as
$$ x^r\cdot e_{r}\bigg(-\frac{r}{c}x^{k-1} \bigg) = z^r$$ with $\color{red}{r=k-1}$ and $\color{red}{z=a-\frac{a^k}{c}}$ which produces
$$\frac{W_r(-\frac{r}{c}z^r)}{-\frac{r}{c}}=x^r$$ and the final solution of your problem:
$$\color{red}{x=\frac{z}{1+\frac{W_r(-\frac{r}{c}z^r)}{r}}}$$

Thanks!
Based on your helpful answer and the reference paper you provided for other similar problems, I have solved the equation efficiently!
Cheers!

The maximum value of x (real) is provided analytically and when it happens, if you wish.... let me know

As Tyma Gaidash writes in the comments, the equation can be transformed to a trinomial-like equation:
$$\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=c$$
$$-cx+x^k-a^k+ac=0$$
$$-\frac{c}{a^k-ac}x+\frac{1}{a^k-ac}x^k-1=0$$
$x\to -\frac{a^k-ac}{c}t$:
$$t-\frac{(a^k-ac)^{k-1}}{c^k}t^k-1=0$$
$k\to\alpha$:
$$t-\frac{(a^\alpha-ac)^{\alpha-1}}{c^\alpha}t^\alpha-1=0$$
$\frac{(a^\alpha-ac)^{\alpha-1}}{c^\alpha}\to y$:
$$t-yt^\alpha-1=0$$
Now the equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent Fox-Wright Function $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $
Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106

Thank you!
This provides me an efficient alternative for my problem!

Hint:
Let us define the irrational function $\;f(x)=x^k\;$ with your data, then:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=f'(a)=\ldots$$
Or also Lagrange's MVT:
$$\frac{x^k-a^k}{x-a}=f'(d)\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;d\in (x,a)\;\;\text{or}\;\;d\in(a,x)$$

Thank you for your time, this tip, while not completely solving the problem, helped me understand my original question！

@Tyke. You're right. Didn't fully understand your question when I posted the above.
